# Expo Web starts Automatically

Tags: react-native, expo

When I run the command "yarn start", the expo web starts automatically, and even if I open the expo client app on my iPhone the link on my app takes me to Safari and opens up a webpage. How can I open the app on expo CLI and not on my phone's browser (Safari)?

I have also tried the command `"expo start --ios"` and when I run it I get the error

> "Simulator not installed. Please visit
> https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/ to download Xcode and the
> iOS simulator. If you already  have the latest version of Xcode
> installed, you may have to run the command `sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app`".

I don't want to run the app on a simulator or phone's browser instead on my phone using expo client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was dealing with this issue also hoping someone would find a solution. However, I have found the solution that worked for me at least. What I did is installed the react-native cli (reinstall if already installed) and then ran npm install in my project and it went back to normal and stopped going on my phones browser. Search documentation regarding this to install those things. I installed them in the order stated and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux try with sudo:

```
sudo npm install -g expo-cli
```

Then install packages and run:

```
yarn
```

Then run the following to clear cache and start expo:

```
expo start -c
```

This issue usually happens when you install a new npm package. You can either uninstall/reinstall the package or run the above three steps and solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try update your expo-cli version and see if it helps. `npm install -g expo-cli`

Answer (score 0):

Below is my situation,

By default Expo uses yarn. I installed any new dependencies using npm, then by default expo is built with web.

Solution:

- use yarn always to install new dependencies or
- use npm install once to install and now expo will build project with android or ios